# C# OrderBy and iOS gives JIT error

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, linq, unity-game-engine

I am trying to reorder an dictionary by using this line:

```
var orderedPairs = myturn.OrderBy(pair => pair.Value.Get<string>("lastMoveTime")).Select(pair => pair.Value);
```

It works perfectly in the editor but when compiling to iOS I get this error:

*ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2>:GetEnumerator ()' while running with --aot-only.*

How do I get passed this? Any ideas anyone? Is there another way to reorder the dictionary?

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

************************** EDIT ***********************

I am trying to get Bunny83's method to work but am a bit over my head. I have done the following:

```
public class MyClass
{
    //public string lastMoveTime{ set; get; }
}

List<MyClass> orderedList = myturn.Values;
orderedList.Sort((e1,e2) => e1.lastMoveTime.CompareTo(e2.lastMoveTime));
```

My issue is. As I see this I am putting the whole ParseObject into MyClass and I don't know how to get the lastMoveTime out of it to compare.

Secondly, if it worked. How do I get everything into my dictionary again in ordered style afterwards?

Still hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2):

How about using my library, [UniLinq](https://github.com/RyotaMurohoshi/UniLinq)?

This is Class library for LINQ to Objects on Unity GameEngine without Exceptions related AOT compile.(But now, this library is Beta)

This library is based on mono class library newer mono than Unity uses.
And I changed some code for Unity's mono compiler.

When we use Unity defualt classes for OrderBy, ThenBy and others, exceptions may be thrown with in some cases.
And I fixed some cases for the exceptions heppning with UniLinq.

Please try [UniLinq](https://github.com/RyotaMurohoshi/UniLinq)!

Answer (score 1):

`OrderBy` will not work on iOS, because of some compilation limitations. This library might help: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/18131

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is that when using OrderBy is creates an instance of an internal generic class called "OrderedEnumerable". A concrete version of this type isn't created ahead of time since it's only used inside a method like OrderBy and the AOT compiler seems to not include extension methods when creating a dependency tree. So the concrete class of OrderedEnumerable for your generic arguments isn't created ahead of time so the runtime has to jit compile which doesn't work on iOS.

The Usual solution is to manually create an instance of that type somewhere in your project so the compiler creates that class for you. However since OrderedEnumerable is an internal class i don't see a way to force-compile that class.

Since you are not interested in the dictionaries "keys", you can simply turn the "Values" into a generic List and sort this list:

```
List<YourClass> orderedList = myturn.Values.ToList();
orderedList.Sort((e1,e2) => e1.Get<string>("lastMoveTime").CompareTo(e2.Get<string>("lastMoveTime")));
```

This should give you an ordered list of "YourClass" type which is ordered by the value returned by the Get method of your class. This should also work on AOT platforms. However I don't have an aot-only device to test it.

***edit***

To clarify a bit more: "YourClass" in my example should be replaced with the class in your Dictionary. You didn't include how your dictionary is declared, but since you called a generic method called "Get" on it i concluded that your dictionary contains some kind of class / struct as value. Your Linq line only returns the values of the dictionary and ignores the key. You ordered your "values" based on the return value of your Get method.

What i did is to copy all value.elements of your dictionary into a Seperate List. Of course that list need to be of the type of your class. The generic List has a built-in [Sort method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and you can pass it a [Comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) delegate to specify how to sort the items in the list. Since in your original code you sorted by the return value of `Get<string>("lastMoveTime")` i did the same. Inside the comparison delegate i simply grab that value from both elements and compare them with each other.

After executing Sort, the list will contain all your classes / structs sorted the way you want them.

Comment: I am trying to get this to work, but am a bit over my head :-/